# Align horizontally a form

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

Good morning everyone,
I have some problem in aligning this form (Contact us) in the middle of the page.
I utilise (I hope so) the flex propriety in a correct way, but why this form isn’t aligning?

So my question for you is:

- Could you help me understand why this form isn’t aligning correctly?
- Also could you suggest a way to align items horizontally and vertically in a proper way because I think my method isn’t correct.

Thanks in advance.

Here the code preview in codepen.io: https://codepen.io/maximo890/pen/oopdaz

CSS

```
.contact-us-form {
background-color: #f8bc3a;

}

.form-container {


}

form {
    margin-top: 100px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;  
    width: 30%;
}
.formgeneric {

    margin-top: 10px;

}
```

HTML

```
<section class="contact-us-form">
                        <div class="text-box-3">
                        <h2>CONTACT US</h2>
                        <p>Donec sed odio dui nulla vilae eli libem</p>
                        </div> 
                            <div class="form-container">
                                <form>
                                <input type="text" name="fname" value="name" id="iname" class="formgeneric">
                                <input type="text" name="email" value="email" id="imail" class="formgeneric">
                                <textarea type="text" name="message" id="imessage" class="formgeneric">Message</textarea>
                                <input id="button" type="submit" value="submit" class="formgeneric">
                                </form>


                            </div>



        </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try `margin:auto`. Remove the `display:flex` property and just use the css below. This will align the form horizontally center.

```
form {
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this Styling for your "Form" Element (Not for Form Container)

```
  form { 
display: block; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
    }
```

and replace "textarea" Style with this one (Width to 100%) :

```
 textarea {
    border: solid white 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: grey;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 300px;
width: 100%;

}
```

It will align them to the Center! It's just because of the Left and Right margins! :-)

<3

Answer (score 0):

- display:flex and flex-direction property is used for  direction the
  container wants to stack the items. not for aligning them.

  and
- for your your center alignment simply wrap your FORM tag into CENTER tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the flex, you can use something like this:

You can change margin and padding accordingly. Also, you also will have to do necessary changes for textArea container.

```
     #iname {
        flex:1;
        background-image: url(/img/contact.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
        margin:auto; 

    }

    #imail{
        flex:1;
        margin:auto; 
        background-image: url(/img/emailat.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
    }

    #imessage {
        flex:1;
        margin:auto; 
        background-image: url(/img/write.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right;
    }


    input {
        flex:1;
        margin:auto; 
        border: white solid 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: 100%;
        color: grey;
    }

    #button {
        margin:auto; 
        flex:1;
        border: #313131 solid 15px;
        background-color: #313131;
        color: white;
        width: 18%;
    }

    textarea {
        flex:1;
        margin:auto; 
        border: solid white 15px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        color: grey;
        margin-top: 15px;
        height: 300px;


}
```

Hope this helps!